# CouchDB Snap won't move data folder

Tags: server, snap, symbolic-link, couchdb

When I attempt to move a data directory for CouchDB, installed via Snap, I am getting a "user database not found" error.

I'm new to `snap`, but have done this with bare Couch installs a couple of times, so I'm starting to be concerned that there is something about `snap` that I'm getting burned by.

**Steps**

```
sudo bash
snap install couchdb
snap start couchdb
snap stop couchdb
vi /var/snap/couchdb/current/etc/local.ini
# edit properties in vi
#  - bind_address = 0.0.0.0
mv /var/snap/couchdb/common /data/couchdb
chown -R root:root /data/couchdb
ln -s /data/couchdb /var/snap/couchdb/common
snap start couchdb
snap logs couchdb
```

This results in a failure stating that the user database does not exist (`ensure_users_db_exists`).

```
2020-01-16T01:54:15Z couchdb.server[13287]: [error] 2020-01-16T01:54:15.316423Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.251.0> -------- CRASH REPORT Process  (<0.251.0>) with 1 neighbors exited with reason: no match of right hand value {not_found,no_db_file} at couch_auth_cache:ensure_users_db_exists/2(line:447) <= couch_auth_cache:open_auth_db/0(line:419) <= couch_auth_cache:reinit_cache/1(line:282) <= couch_auth_cache:init/1(line:164) <= gen_server:init_it/6(line:328) <= proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3(line:247) at gen_server:init_it/6(line:352) <= proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3(line:247); initial_call: {couch_auth_cache,init,['Argument__1']}, ancestors: [couch_secondary_services,couch_sup,<0.212.0>], messages: [], links: [<0.221.0>,<0.253.0>], dictionary: [], trap_exit: true, status: running, heap_size: 610, stack_size: 27, reductions: 350
2020-01-16T01:54:15Z couchdb.server[13287]: [error] 2020-01-16T01:54:15.318704Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.212.0> -------- Error starting Apache CouchDB:
2020-01-16T01:54:15Z couchdb.server[13287]:     {error,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,couch_secondary_services,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,auth_cache,{{badmatch,{not_found,no_db_file}},[{couch_auth_cache,ensure_users_db_exists,2,[{file,"src/couch_auth_cache.erl"},{line,447}]},{couch_auth_cache,open_auth_db,0,[{file,"src/couch_auth_cache.erl"},{line,419}]},{couch_auth_cache,reinit_cache,1,[{file,"src/couch_auth_cache.erl"},{line,282}]},{couch_auth_cache,init,1,[{file,"src/couch_auth_cache.erl"},{line,164}]},{gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,328}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,247}]}]}}}}}}
```

Alternately to that setup, I also edited the `local.ini` to

```
data_directory = /data/couchdb/data
view_index_directory = /data/couchdb/data
```

With the same issue. (I suspect *this* changes the path within the container?)

**The Story (in case it gives a clue)**

For a hobby project, I have a bare `Ubuntu Server 19` install with two partitions (a bigger "data" drive and a smaller "everything else") and then installed CouchDB as a Snap (re-purpose of some old hardware)

Immediately after getting it up and running, I replicated a "healthy" sized dataset from my laptop to the server, and then freshened all the indexes. I ran out of drive space because Couch is installed on the OS partition. I then moved the data folder over to the data partition at which point I get continuous errors from Couch.